# Function within a function: cramer function "Error in loglin"

Tags: r, function, custom-function

I tried to embed the `cramer` function from `sjstats` package. Although the function works perfectly outside the custom function, it doesn't work within it.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
library (sjstats)    
cramer2 <- function(dta, x, y){
effsize <- cramer(x ~ y, data = dta)
  return(effsize)
}

cramer2(x=gender, y=age, dta=df)
```

> Error in loglin(data, margins, start = start, fit = fitted, param = param, :
> falsche Spezifikationen für 'table' oder 'start'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `x` and `y` are not automatically substituted in a formula for the variables you have passed. Look:

```r
f <- function(x, y) {
  return(x ~ y)
}

f(a, b)
#> x ~ y
```

If you want the variables substituted, you can do something like

```r
f2 <- function(x, y) {
   call("~", substitute(x), substitute(y))
}

f2(a, b)
#> a ~ b
```

So in your case you can do:

```r
library (sjstats)    

cramer2 <- function(dta, x, y) {
  
  f <- as.formula(call("~", substitute(x), substitute(y)))
  effsize <- cramer(f, data = dta)
  return(effsize)
}
```

Obviously we don't have your data, but using the built-in data set `efc` we can demonstrate this works as expected:

```r
data(efc)

cramer2(efc, e16sex, c161sex)
#> [1] 0.05258249
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I do this I get... Error in UseMethod("cramer") : 
  no applicable method for 'cramer' applied to an object of class "call"

Comment: @R.Isabel see my update - this should work for you now, as demonstrated in the reprex

Comment: If I might ask a follow-up question: In the formula we are adapting, the variables are specified with quotation marks, so for the formula above it would be cramer2(x="var1", y="var2", data=df). I found that through the function, the quotation marks are copied from the formula but this returns an error for the original cramer function. I've tried removing the quotation marks with noquote within as.formula(call("~", substitute(x), substitute(y))) but this did not work as intended (it still returns "var1" ~ "var2"). Thank you very much again!

Comment: @R.Isabel the function above should work without quotation marks, as long as the variables are present in the passed data frame.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Allan works perfectly fine if your function does not target the variables with quotation marks, i.e. `customfunction(dta=mydata, x= gender,  y=age, weight=dataweight)`.

If, however, you must for some reason target the variables *with* quotation marks, e.g. `customfunction(dta=mydata, x= "gender",  y="age", weight="dataweight").`
Then replace `substitute` with `sym`:

```
library (sjstats)    
cramer2 <- function(dta, x, y) {
  f <- as.formula(call("~", sym(x), sym(y)))
  effsize <- cramer(f, weights=dta[[weight]], data = dta)
  return(effsize)
}
```